# How to make mobile app fit the screen

Tags: android, html, ios, cordova, user-interface

I am maintaining a hybrid mobile app that does not fit the screen (overflow).
I made changement on the viewport meta tag but it didn't fix the problem. 
Is there any suggestion to fix the problem ?

Heres the meta tags i am using.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; user-scalable=no; initial-scale=1; minimum-scale=1; maximum-scale=1">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
<meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#222222">
```

[image: this is a screenshot of the app in iphone 6+]

Comment: try to use css media queries to write your css

Comment: i'm using this "width=device-width", it should be enough, no ?

Comment: try like this. <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width , user-scalable=no , initial-scale=1 , minimum-scale=1 , maximum-scale=1">. use , instead of ;

Comment: already using it, i've mentionned it in the question :)

Comment: have you checked this in your device instead of checking in console?

Comment: yes i did and still the same problem

Comment: It might be useful to post your CSS so people can see if there's anything in there that might cause this.